# Mysql subquery, categories and its items

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

Could somebody help me, or point me in the right direction?
I'm trying query all catergories and then its items within one query so that i can loop through the data like so.

```
foreach($categories as $category){
    echo $category->name;
    foreach($category->items as $item){
        echo $item->name;
    }
}
```

I just need to see an example and i'll get it,
Thank you in advance.

Comment: We need to see your mysql query.
But I think you don't need two loops, I think you subquery add col to your results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are two tables, `category` and `item`. 1 category has zero or one more items. (you are using 2 depth loop)

- category(c_id, c_name)
- item(i_id, c_id, i_name)

then you could accomplish like this:

```
SELECT c.c_name, i.i_name
FROM category c LEFT JOIN item i USING(c_id)
```

When category and item has many to many relationship, you have three tables,

- category(c_id, c_name)
- item(i_id, i_name)
- category_item(c_id, i_id)

you can something like this. (in this case, your PHP code should look like 3 depth loop)

```
SELECT c.c_name, i.i_name
FROM category c LEFT JOIN category_item ci USING(c_id)
  INNER JOIN item i USING(i_id)
```